# Make my server not browsable by IP address

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I am setting up an apache server and I would like to so if someone were to try to browse my ip address, it would just not do anything, or return error 403, rather than default to the first virtual host on it.

How do I go about to get that accomplished?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remove the default vitual host from your configuration or configure error document in default vitual host.